# SQL Server stored procedure is calculating a wrong average per state

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, average

I have two tables

`Funddetails`:

```
 FundId  Fund   Industry State    Column1
 -----------------------------------------
     1     1        2      NSW             
     2     1        2      ACT         
     3     1        2      VIC          
     4     1        2      NSW         
     5     1        2      ACT         
     6     1        2      VIC         
     7     1        2      NSW          
     8     1        2      ACT         
     9     1        2      VIC
```

`Industrydetail`:

```
IndustryId price State
-----------------------
   1         12   NSW
   2         1    Vic
   3         3    ACT
```

This is how I am updating column 1

```
UPDATE FundDetails
SET Column1 = CASE 
                WHEN (funddetails.Industry * Industrydetails.price -
                         (select Avg(funddetails.Industry * Industrydetails.price) OVER (partition BY Industrydetails.state)) <= -5 
                   THEN '50' 
                   ELSE '100' 
              END
FROM FundDetails 
INNER JOIN Industrydetails ON FundDetails.State = Industrydetails.State
```

But the average calculation is giving wrong result.

`funddetails.Industry*Industrydetails.price` and `(select Avg(funddetails.Industry*Industrydetails.price)  OVER (partition BY Industrydetails.state))` are giving same results.

Is there any other way to get the

```
average(funddetails.Industry * Industrydetails.price)
```

per state and update the column

Comment: FWIW: AVG(INT) -> INT.

Comment: sorry what is this

Comment: How is the average calculation wrong?

Comment: The sample data you give has all the industry values in your fund table the same, but I'm guessing the issue is with this part: `(select Avg(funddetails.Industry*Industrydetails.price)  OVER (partition BY Industrydetails.state))` get rid of the select and simply use `Avg(funddetails.Industry*Industrydetails.price)  OVER (partition BY Industrydetails.state)` and see if that gives the result you're expecting.

Comment: @ZLK if i remove select then i am getting error Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: Right. Try this, then: `UPDATE T SET Column1 = newVal FROM (SELECT f.industry, i.price, f.column1, CASE WHEN industry * price - avg(f.industry*i.price) over (partition by i.state) <= -5 THEN '50' ELSE '100' END newVal FROM Funddetails f JOIN Industrydetail i ON i.state = f.state) T;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH AvgIndustryPrice (State, AverageIndustryPrice) AS
(
    SELECT
        FundDetails.State,
        AVG (FundDetails.Industry * IndustryDetail.Price)
    FROM
        FundDetails
    JOIN
        IndustryDetail
    ON
        FundDetails.State = IndustryDetail.State
    GROUP BY
        FundDetails.State
)
UPDATE
    FundDetails
SET
    Column1 = 
    CASE 
        WHEN funddetails.Industry * Industrydetails.price - AvgIndustryPrice.AverageIndustryPrice <= -5 
        THEN '50' 
        ELSE '100' 
    END
FROM
    FundDetails
JOIN
    AvgIndustryPrice
ON
    FundDetails.State = AvgIndustryPrice.State
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query gives right answer.
you added the data in table in such way that gives same result for both (funddetails.Industry * Industrydetails.price) and AVG (FundDetails.Industry * IndustryDetail.Price)